SSAI Ad Impressions has (%50 - 55% ) invalid only doubleclick
We have developed serverside ad injection software, but we are having a problem only with doubleclick, almost half of the traffic is invalidated on days with high traffic in prime time.
When we examine the logs, we do not find any bot ip or bot agent.
We are making thousands of ad impressions at the same time only for radio broadcasters who enter the advertisement simultaneously.
If there is no high traffic, our invalid figures drop to 5%.
Why do you think half of the impressions made during high traffic hours are considered invalid?
How can we fix this problem?
thanks
Cenk
We want our SSAI Software to make a better impression as expected.
We tried many fixed and variable parameters but the result did not change.
thanks
